Excel VBA Gross Profit / (Loss) Formula
I need help with VBA formula to calculate the Gross Profit/(Loss).  Total Revenue (cell B11 is subject to change) - Total Cost of Goods Sold

Here's what I've tried
Cells.Find(What:="Gross Profit / (Loss)", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-60]C-R[-1]C"

This formula is what I need help with:
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-60]C-R[-1]C"
This portion of the formula is fine -R[-1]C"
How do I make this dynamic? =R[-60]C
On the next P&L the Total Revenue may be cell B14

A good technic if you want to create a formula for VBA to make the formula directly in the cell (can easily test and adjust), and then in the immediate window get the actual formula of the cell. Something like this: ?Range("B71").FormulaR1C1
In this case VLOOKUP is used to find the dynamic value.
Put in a cell (B71) =VLOOKUP("Total Revenue";A:B;2;FALSE)-B70 and then in the immediate window the returned formula is: =VLOOKUP("Total Revenue",C[-1]:C,2,FALSE)-R[-1]C
This can be used in the VBA code.  Quotes should be double quoted.
